# Tab layout inside Tab layout

Tags: android

i have develop one application in which tab layout in main file now i would like to set   tablayout inside 2nd number tab,so what thing can i do? help me.
its "tab inside tab"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to give sub-options while clicking on 2nd tab button. For that, why dont you create layout with 2-3 options as you wants. And make it visible/invisible based on the 2nd button's click.

You can make visible/invisible any view by using **`setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`** and **`setVisibility(View.GONE)`** method.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can't embed a TabHost inside another TabHost. You can do what @Paresh said. Implement your own view switching. If you want an entire Activity embedded - take a look at ActivityGroup or the Fragments framework which you can use through the Compatibility Framework. Good luck.